# How can I update over a linked server with code first migration?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, linked-server

I am using entity framework 6 with code first.  During deployment I need to make an update across and existing linked server.  When I try this I get:

"MSDTC on server 'myLocal' is unavailable."

This problem happens when running agianst my local instance.  MSDTC is not enabled on that instance but I have no trouble running this update manually in SQL Server.  I don't want every developer to have to enable MSDTC for this one command.

I have tried adding this as a migration using a DbMigration.Sql and I get the error.  I have also tried it in the seed method of DbMigrationsConfiguration using context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand and I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET Transaction scopes that go across servers - including linked servers - will automatically start the Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC). I think your best bet is to update the other database with a direct call in the migration, rather than through the linked server.